# Confusion about the tensor product and matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, notation, tensor-products

This is a question I came across looking at special relativity and tensor products.

For example, we have the metric tensor and its corresponding matrix representation
$$ g_{\mu\nu} =  g^{\mu\nu} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
which looks the same in co- and contravariant form. Another example would be the Lorentz transformation along the $x$-axis given by: 
 $$ {\Lambda^\mu}_{\nu} =\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma\beta & 0 & 0 \\
-\gamma\beta & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the electromagnetic field:
$$ F^{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0              &  E_x & E_y & E_z \\
    E_x &  0              & -B_z            &  B_y   \\
    E_y &  B_z            &  0              & -B_x   \\
    E_z & -B_y            &  B_x            &  0
  \end{bmatrix} $$

If we want to calculate the form of $F^{\mu\nu}$ in a moving coordinate frame we have to transform the elelectromagnetic field tensor:
$$F'^{\mu\nu} = {\Lambda^\mu}_{\alpha} {\Lambda^\nu}_{\beta} F^{\alpha\beta}$$

This is sometimes calculated as a matrix product 
$$ F' = \Lambda F \Lambda $$

My question is now whether there is a simple way to see this product from the above notation using the indices. I think the right matrix $\Lambda$ should actually be a transpose (it does not matter for the given example). Is there a generalization for this?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the implicit sums in that expression explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

In index notation, matrix multiplication takes the following form:
$$
(AB)_{i}^j=A_{i}^kB_{k}^j,
$$
which for three matrices (relevant to the case at hand) looks like this:
$$
(ABC)_{i}^j=A_{i}^kB_{k}^lC_l^j.
$$
Thus, we may write
$$
(\Lambda F\Lambda)_{\mu}^{\nu}=\Lambda_\mu^\alpha F_\alpha^\beta\Lambda_\beta^\nu.
$$
We can rewrite this as
$$
\Lambda_\mu^\alpha \Lambda_\beta^\nu F_\alpha^\beta.
$$
Finally, note that $\Lambda_\mu^\alpha F_\alpha^\beta = \Lambda^\mu_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta}$ (since $\Lambda$ is a symmetric matrix), giving the expression
$$
\Lambda_\alpha^\mu \Lambda_\beta^\nu F^{\alpha\beta}.
$$

Comment: This takes nicely care of the numeric values, but I can't help thinking there ought to be some notation to handle how the left index of $F$ is apparently being raised and lowered using $I=\Delta(1,1,1,1)$ instead of $g=\Delta(1,-1,-1,-1)$. Perhaps it would be clearer to stagger the indices?